# MongoDB Community problem with MacOS Homebrew

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew, tap

About This Mac:
Apple M1 macOS Big Sur Version 11.6

Homebrew Version:

```
some@some ~ % brew -v
Homebrew 3.3.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision fdd4c67dbc1; last commit 2021-10-25)
```

Warnings:

```
some@some ~ % brew tap mongodb/brew         
==> Tapping mongodb/brew
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 760, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (257/257), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (184/184), done.
remote: Total 760 (delta 119), reused 127 (delta 70), pack-reused 503
Receiving objects: 100% (760/760), 167.21 KiB | 1.40 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (357/357), done.
Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-database-tools.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@4.2.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@3.6.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@3.2.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@3.4.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@4.0.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community-shell.rb:10

Warning: Calling bottle :unneeded is deprecated! There is no replacement.
Please report this issue to the mongodb/brew tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
  /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/mongodb/homebrew-brew/Formula/mongodb-community@4.4.rb:10

Tapped 14 formulae (30 files, 231.1KB).
```

I can not use mongodb-community@5.0 or mongodb-community@4.4

Why am I getting these warnings?

How can I fix these warnings?

Comment: I, personally, am not a fan of package managers on macOS. If I use `MongoDB` directly from the web page, downloaded as `tar` package, it simply works. On both `Intel` and `M1`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the sililar problem
I reinstaled it

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and i pressed RETURN to continue
then I run this command:

```
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
```

after I coud run this:

```
brew install mongodb-community@5.0
```

and for run MongoDB

```
brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

After what I coud conect to my db.

And when I want to stop MongoDB

```
brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```